# Lightbox killing javascript form options

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, lightbox

so I am having a tricky problem with a form I am using. so it is placed within a Lightbox which works fine. The problem is there is an option that switches the options that follow depending on what you have selected before.

This works outside of the Lightbox but failing when in the Lightbox within the form.

I am using this example: [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sabithpocker/fRuhn/)

So am loading this first within the header:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="release/featherlight.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Here is the part of the form causing the problem:

```
<div class="lightbox" id="fl1">


    <form>

    <select name="select1" id="select1">
    <option value="1">Fruit</option>
    <option value="2">Animal</option>
    <option value="3">Bird</option>
    <option value="4">Car</option>
    </select>


    <select name="select2" id="select2">
    <option value="1">Banana</option>
    <option value="1">Apple</option>
    <option value="1">Orange</option>
    <option value="2">Wolf</option>
    <option value="2">Fox</option>
    <option value="2">Bear</option>
    <option value="3">Eagle</option>
    <option value="3">Hawk</option>
    <option value="4">BWM<option>
    </select>

    </form>
</div>
```

These two scripts follow at the bottom of the page:

```
<script>

$("#select1").change(function() { 
if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
    /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
    $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
var id = $(this).val();
var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
$('#select2').html(options);
});

</script>
```

Comment: Can nobody help at all? I am really struggling with this...

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is, or what you are trying to achieve here. The fiddle didn't make it much easier to understand for me either. Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Hint: $("#select1").change(function() this fails when loaded into lightbox. You need to use .on() (or .live() with earlier versions of jquery)

Comment: By changing from.change to .on() will that actually work? the script he is using works outside of the lightbox but not inside?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not super familiar with the lightbox library you're using. I couldnt quite figure out how to hide the original div and keep the overlay content showing up. It's weird, because it duplicates the elements, so what's happening is you're binding to the original, but the new ones that get created do not have it.

http://jsfiddle.net/fRuhn/940/ Updated the fiddle, but here's the code:

```
<select name="select1" class="select1">
<option value="1">Fruit</option>
<option value="2">Animal</option>
<option value="3">Bird</option>
<option value="4">Car</option>
</select>


<select name="select2" class="select2">
<option value="1">Banana</option>
<option value="1">Apple</option>
<option value="1">Orange</option>
<option value="2">Wolf</option>
<option value="2">Fox</option>
<option value="2">Bear</option>
<option value="3">Eagle</option>
<option value="3">Hawk</option>
<option value="4">BWM<option>
</select>
```

Changed to classes over ids, so i could bind to the proper select. Then i put your event binding into a function:

```
function bindEvents() {
  $(".select1").change(function() { 
    if($(this).data('options') == undefined){
      /*Taking an array of all options-2 and kind of embedding it on the select1*/
      $(this).data('options',$('#select2 option').clone());
    } 
    var id = $(this).val();
    var options = $(this).data('options').filter('[value=' + id + ']');
    $('.select2').html(options);
  });
}
```

Then in the featherlight call, add an afterOpen:

```
$('a').featherlight({
    targetAttr: 'href',
    afterOpen: function () {
      bindEvents();
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't fix the dropdown code, because that wasnt the original issue :)

Comment: The original issue being that the change isn;t working within the lightbox. But where have you resolved this?